What's the syntax of "You look like someone starved a virgin to death"?
source: "Silicon Valley" Season 01 Episode 02 "The Cap Table"

You look like someone starved a virgin to death.

(https://silicon-valley.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cap_Table)
I understand:
You look like someone who/that starved a virgin to death.
You look like someone who/that starves a virgin to death.
You look like someone starving a virgin to death.
You look like someone starved by a virgin to death.
You look like someone starved of/for a virgin to death.
However, what's "You look like someone starved a virgin to death"?

It has the same sense as the wordier sentence "You look the way it would look like if someone starved a virgin to death".
"Someone starved a virgin to death" is a subordinate clause, where "someone" is the subject, "starved" is a transitive verb in the past tense form (here used to describe a hypothetical situation), "a virgin" is the direct object, and "to death" is a to-infinitive that acts as a complement to the verb starve, emphasizing and exaggerating the sense of the verb.
The sentence suggests that if someone starved a virgin to death, the way that virgin would look is the way that Jared (the one who the pronoun "you" is referring to) looks.

I interpret it as meaning: 1. “You look like someone [who has/had]  starved a virgin to death.” Which doesn't make much sense unless we know something about the plot. Logically, looking like "a starved virgin" must belong to "you" but syntactically it doesn't add up.

@Mari-LouA: A bit more context for the quote is as follows: "Sorry if I scared you, I know I have somewhat ghost-like features. My uncle used to say, 'You look like someone starved a virgin to death.'" I think this establishes that the sentence describes "you" as looking like the starved virgin, not like the person doing the starving

That helps to clear up my perplexity. Thank you.

You have my upvote. But also worth mentioning that only semantics tell you this. You can't deduce it from the grammar. "You look like someone threw up on a carpet" is grammatically identical, but clearly means "You look like you would in reaction to someone throwing up" not "you look like vomit that someone threw up".

Obviously there's something odd about such constructions:

You look like a dog threw up.

The practical meaning is

You look  disgusting, like dog vomit.

Not

You look disgusted, as if reacting to a dog that has just thrown up.

How do we get to that practical meaning? How can you look like an act?
I suppose the answer is that the act of throwing up is metonymic for its result:

You look like "a dog threw up" => vomit.

Similarly, "someone starved a virgin to death" resolves metonymically to  "an emaciated girl", "a girl who had been starved to death".
"Virgin" denotes more than youth, of course, and the act of starving a girl to death has misogyny lurking below the surface, but we won't pursue that angle here. That's better asked on the psychology forum.

“You look like someone has starved a virgin to death.”
“You” is being told that their appearance is that of a starved virgin. If someone were to starve a virgin to death, it would look like “you.”
